# Getting the Postal code outside the google JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to retrieve a postal code from a longitude and latitude. Therefore I use the google API.

Here is my request.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.04166373133121,5.580196380615234&sensor=true

When you enter this in you browser you will see the entire JSON. Here is only a part of it.

JSON File

```
   {

      "results": [
                  {
                  "address_components": [
                                       {
                                           "long_name": "2",
                                           "short_name": "2",
                                           "types": [
                                                     "street_number"
                                                     ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "long_name": "Hermisweg",
                                           "short_name": "Hermisweg",
                                           "types": [
                                                     "route"
                                                     ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "long_name": "Opglabbeek",
                                           "short_name": "Opglabbeek",
                                           "types": [
                                                     "locality",
                                                     "political"
                                                     ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "long_name": "Limburg",
                                           "short_name": "LI",
                                           "types": [
                                                     "administrative_area_level_2",
                                                     "political"
                                                     ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "long_name": "Vlaams Gewest",
                                           "short_name": "Vlaams Gewest",
                                           "types": [
                                                     "administrative_area_level_1",
                                                     "political"
                                                     ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "long_name": "België",
                                           "short_name": "BE",
                                           "types": [
                                                     "country",
                                                     "political"
                                                     ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "long_name": "3660",
                                           "short_name": "3660",
                                           "types": [
                                                     "postal_code"
                                                     ]
                                       }
                              ]
                      }
               ]
       }
```

My question is now how I can get the postal code from this JSON? In this example I want 3660 as output.

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: So what is your question? How to read JSON? This has nothing to do with Google Maps.

Comment: @Marcelo I know how to read the json. But I can't get the postal code out of the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inside `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *thexml=[[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    id allValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[thexml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&jsonError];

    if(jsonError!=nil)
        NSLog(@"JsonError: %@",jsonError);


    NSArray *result = [(NSDictionary*)allValues objectForKey:@"results"];
    for(int i=0;i<[result count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *values = (NSDictionary*)[result objectAtIndex:i];                        

        NSArray *component = [(NSDictionary*)values objectForKey:@"address_components"];

        for(int j=0;j<[component count];j++)
        {
            NSDictionary *parts = (NSDictionary*)[component objectAtIndex:j];
            if([[parts objectForKey:@"types"] containsObject:@"postal_code"])
            {
                NSLog(@"Postal Code : %@ ",[parts objectForKey:@"long_name"]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want "3600" whose key is "long_name" ... so you want "long_name" basically .

Try This :-

suppose you are getting all the result in resultDict .

```
NSString *long_name = [[[[[resultDict objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address_components"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"long_name"];

NSLog(@"long_name is %@",long_name);
```

Note :- You will have to replace the 0 with the for loop's variable (for example "i") , put there the number of elements in array you get in the result dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Map this JSON into a NSDictionary class. From this you can access the address_components  array.

Use array objectAtIndex to get required value.

IF you need a comprehensive solution go for Abstract KVC wrapper classes available in github

These directly map JSON into model classes.

Once mapped, you can access these by specifying : object.property of these classes.